# Question regarding NIntegrate using the Arg function

Tags: numerical-integration

I am having some trouble when trying to evaluate this simple integral using `NIntegrate`:

```
NIntegrate[Cos[t + Arg[ (-I + 4 t)]], {t, 0., 1.}]
```

The error message is

> NIntegrate::nlim: t = Arg[-I+4 t] is not a valid limit of integration.

There are ways of avoiding this problem, such as choosing the integration method (`Method -> "Trapezoidal"`.) What is not clear to me is where this error is coming from. If I plot the function being integrated, there is no issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NIntegrate` attempts a bit of symbolic analysis of the integrand before integrating. That seems to be messing something up. Hide your function from symbolic analysis:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Cos[t + Arg[(-I + 4 t)]]
NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0., 1.}]
(* 0.815624 *)
```

Comment: also `NIntegrate[Cos[t + Arg[(-I + 4 t)]], {t, 0., 1.}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]`.